# How do I remove a < char from a string?

Tags: jquery, string, datatables

I have in a string something like " < aaa > " that is not displayed on my jquery datatable. How can I remove the < / > from the string? I reached the text and it enters here:

```
if(op.startsWith("<"))
```

but I don't know how to remove the "<". This doesn't works:

```
op = op.replace("<","");
```

Comment: It will be better to give an example with sample input and output

Comment: somebody responded me  op = op.replaceAll("[<>]", ""); and it works but I don't know where the answer is gone...?!?

Answer (score 0):

Text `< aaa >` is treated as HTML tag, and that is why it's not displayed. You need to encode the special characters in order to display the string correctly instead of removing the special characters.

Use the following jQuery one-liner to correctly encode `<`, `>` and other special characters in your string.

```
$('<div/>').text('< aaa >').html();
```

See example below for demonstration.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
document.write(
  $('<div/>').text('< aaa >').html()
);
</script>
```